# What is wrong with this CDF calculation?

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, distribution-theory

---

__________________Newly Inserted______________

From below mentioned accepted answer, I am facing some further difficulties.

However, in $0\leq x \leq 1$ the area under PDF is coming as $0.9749$ and in the range of $1\leq x \leq 2$, when I am integrating

$\int_1^22 \arcsin \left( \frac 2 x - 1 \right)dx$ by substitution method $t=(\frac{2}{x}−1)$ and on proceeding we get

${\pi}-\int_0^1\frac{4}{(1+t)(\sqrt{(1-t^2)}}dt$, on integrating the following integral again by substitution of $t=sin\theta$, it is coming as

$\pi-\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^0\frac{4}{1+sin\theta}d\theta$, which is becoming divergent.

So, please tell me how the area under this PDF becomes $1$.

Your help will be appreciated.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the pdfs of $\hat X$ and $\hat Y$ are zero outside $(0, 1)$. The convolution of the pdfs can be split into two integrals:
$$f_{\hat X + \hat Y}(x) =
(f_{\hat X} * f_{\hat Y})(x) = \\
\int_0^x f_{\hat X}(\tau) f_{\hat Y}(x - \tau) d\tau \,[0 < x < 1] + \\
\int_{x - 1}^1 f_{\hat X}(\tau) f_{\hat Y}(x - \tau) d\tau \,[1 < x < 2].$$
If $f_{\hat X}(x) = f_{\hat Y}(x) = (1/\sqrt x - 1)[0 < x < 1]$,
$$f_{\hat X + \hat Y}(x) =
(x - 4 \sqrt x + \pi) [0 < x < 1] + \\
\left( 2 \arcsin \left( \frac 2 x - 1 \right) + 4 \sqrt {x - 1} - x - 2 \right)
 [1 < x < 2], \\
f_{X + Y}(x) =
\frac 1 {a^2} f_{\hat X + \hat Y} \left( \frac x {a^2} \right).$$

Comment: Thanks for your kind help. But I did not get properly, some little more explanation may much helpful for me. Thank you very much, Sir.

Comment: We need $0 < \tau < 1 \land 0 < x - \tau < 1$, or $0 < \tau < 1 \land x - 1 < \tau < x$. When $0 < x < 1$, that reduces to $0 < \tau < x$, giving the integral that you've computed. But you also need to consider what happens when $1 < x < 2$. If something else is unclear, please be more specific with your question.

Comment: The integration of $\int_1^2 2 \arcsin \left( \frac 2 x - 1 \right)dx$ is divergent.

Comment: $\arcsin(2/x - 1)$ is continuous and bounded on $[1, 2]$, how can the integral be divergent? To verify that the pdf integrates to $1$, use
$$\int \arcsin \left( \frac 2 x - 1 \right) dx =
x \arcsin \left( \frac 2 x - 1 \right) + 2 \sqrt {x - 1}.$$

Comment: How did you solve it sir? I want to get those process by which you solved it. Take my respect sir.

Comment: If you mean finding the antiderivative of $\arcsin(2/x - 1)$, I just looked it up. Your method is fine, except that the sign in front of $\pi$ is reversed, it should have been $-\pi - \int_{\pi / 2}^0 4/(1 + \sin t) dt$ (which isn't divergent). Then there is a standard substitution to reduce the integrand to a rational function.