# Find the probability that $(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2<1/4$

Tags: probability

I was trying to solve for $P((a-c)^2+(b-d)^2<1/4)$ where $a,b,c,d$ are independent and uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. One thing that I found online was $a-c$ has a triangular distribution.

I think that you have to find the probability cumulative function, but I don't know how to do that. Though I am willing to look through some resources which could point to how to solve these kinds of problems. I briefly looked through a probability and statistics textbook, but couldn't find what I needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X_1, X_2,X_3,X_4$ be iid (independant identically distributed) Unif[0,1] random variables. Let

$$D:=(X_1-X_2)^2 \ \ \ \text{and}  \ \ \ E:=(X_3-X_4)^2.$$

The pdf of $X_1-X_2$ is known to be the "tent function" with support on $[-1,1]$ (its equation is $f(x)=1-|x|(-1\le x\le 1)$ but we do not need it).

$$P(D<x)=P((X_1-X_2)^2<x)=P(|X_1-X_2|^2<x)=P(-\sqrt{x} \le |X_1-X_2|<\sqrt{x})=1-(1-\sqrt{x})^2 \tag{1}$$

(the last equality comes from a geometrical reasoning on the shape of the tent function: total area minus the area of 2 triangles on the left and right side).

(1) means that the cdf of Random Variable $D$ is

$F_D(x)=1-(1-\sqrt{x})^2=2 \sqrt{x}-x$

Therefore, by derivation, the associated pdf is:

$$f_D(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1 \ \ \text{for} \ \ 0 \le x \le 1\tag{2}$$

$E$ has the same pdf as $D$.

The pdf of their sum $D+E$ is the convolution of their pdf, i.e., (obtained through Wolfram Alpha: see remark at the bottom)

$$f_{D+E}(a)=\pi+a-4\sqrt{a} \ \  \text{when} \ \ 0<a<1 \tag{2}$$

(if $a>1$ there is a different expression for $f_{D+E}(a)$, but we do not need it here; see Remark below).

Therefore, by integration, its cdf is

$$F_{D+E}(a)=\pi a + \frac12 a^2 - \frac83 a\sqrt{a}$$

Here is now the final computation:

$$P(D+E<1/4)=F_{D+E}(1/4)=\pi/4-29/96 \approx 0.483315$$

**Remark** dealing with the obtention of the convolution. I have asked to Wolfram Alpha the indefinite integral (primitive function):

$$\Phi(x)=\int \underbrace{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1\right)}_{f_D(x)}\underbrace{\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a-x}}-1\right)}_{f_E(a-x)}dx \tag{3}$$

$$\Phi(x)=x+2(\sqrt{a-x}-\sqrt{x})+2 \arcsin \sqrt{\tfrac{x}{a}}$$

out of which the cdf of $D+E$ is obtained

$$F_{D+E}(x)=\left[\Phi(x)\right]_{x=0}^{x=a}$$

giving relationship (3).

In fact, if one needs for further calculations to consider values of $a$ in interval $(1,2)$, one should write (2) under the form:

$$f_D(x)=(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1)_+=(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}-1)(0 \le x \le 1)$$

the "+" index meaning "positive part" and the multiplication by $(0 \le x \le 1)$ meaning "multiplication by $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$".

For all this, see [this paper](https://people.kth.se/%7Ejohanph/habc.pdf) and [this one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233329353_The_distance_between_random_points_in_rectangles) generalizing these computations (in particular with different versions of integral similar to (3)).

**Remark:** the computation of (3) can as well be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2953919).

Answer (score 0):

The quantity $(a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2$ is the square of the distance between the coordinates $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, where we clearly have both points independent and identically distributed uniformly in the unit square $[0,1]^2$.  Thus, your probability is geometrically equivalent to asking for the probability that two points, picked uniformly at random in the unit square, will be less than $1/2$ units apart.  How might you reason from this point forward?

Comment: This was the problem I was originally trying to solve. I don't know how I'd solve it without just computing it directly.

Comment: @alduan This is why it is important to include context in your question.  If you don't describe how the question arose, you will not get the kind of answers you are looking for.

Comment: The probability $p(x,y)$ that a randomly chosen point in the unit square is within $1/2$ unit of the particular point $(x,y)$ is the area within the circle of radius $1/2$ centered at $(x,y)$ that lies within the unit square. A formula for this is probably tricky to work out, but possible. I’d start by drawing sketches of how the circle and square can overlap. If you can do that, then you can find the average of that probability over the unit square using a double integral: $\int_0^1\int_0^1 p(x,y)\,dy\,dx$.